# How to output results from JOIN query

Tags: php, html, sql, join, inner-join

Appreciate any help in advance!

I have a DB with three tables, exp table, var table and val table.

**exp table**
experimentid
field1
field2
field3
etc...

**var table**
variableid 
field1
field2
field3
experimentid
etc..

**val table**
valueid 
field1
field2
field3 
variableid
etc...

The tables have a 1 to many relationship, meaning there are many vars per exp and many vals per var.

So i wrote a query that will join the tables based on the PKs and FKs.

```
SELECT experiments.experimentid, experiments.field1, variable.variableid, variable.field1, value.valueid, value.field1
FROM exp table
INNER JOIN var table
ON variable.experimentid=experiments.experimentid
INNER JOIN val table
ON value.variableid=variable.variableid
```

My output looks something like this (abbreviated)

```
Experimentid | field1 | variableid | field 1 | valueid | field 1

1 | homepage | 1 | basket | 1 | true
1 | homepage | 1 | basket | 2 | true
1 | homepage | 2 | cart | 3 | false
```

My question is when I output the results, I only want to show the experiment field1 once.  For example, you'll notice I have 3 results, all associated with "homepage".  Well, I only want homepage to be displayed once, but output the numerous variables and values for that experiment.  How can I accomplish this?  I hope I wasn't too cryptic with my DB schema...info is somewhat sensitive.

**UPDATE:**

I'd like my output to look like this (based on the table data above).
Essentially, I only want homepage displayed once, and then the variableid's and valueid's are output as many times as they are relevant.  Somehow I cannot get

```
  <table>
  <tr><td colspan=2>Homepage</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Basket</td><td>cart</td></tr>
  <tr><td>True</td><td>false</td></tr>
  <tr><td>True</td><td>null</td></tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: You said `For example, you'll notice I have 3 results, all associated with "homepage". Well, I only want homepage to be displayed once` . For this you have to apply: `group by field1`, then you will have only 1 result

Comment: If you care how it looks, you should not just print the output from the DB client, but write an application that does the formatting. Maybe you could show us how you imagine the output?

Comment: @Szocske just updated my question with output.  Let me know if you would like me to output the actual result I am getting from the DB...that might be better than the abbreviated example I am providing.

Answer (score 0):

I used this javascript function once to join/combine all rows, vertically adjacent, with the same value:

```
<script>
function joinRows() {
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    for (var i = table.rows.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
        row = table.rows[i];
        for (var j = row.cells.length-1; j>=0 ; j--) {
            col = row.cells[j];
            if(col.innerHTML==table.rows[i-1].cells[j].innerHTML) {
                var addRows = table.rows[i].cells[j].rowSpan;
                table.rows[i].deleteCell(j);
                table.rows[i-1].cells[j].rowSpan = table.rows[i-1].cells[j].rowSpan + addRows;
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

The html code below to test it:

```
<table id="myTable" border="1">
<tr>
<td id="td.1.1">1.1</td>
<td id="td.1.2">2.2</td>
<td id="td.1.3">1.3</td>
<td id="td.1.3">1.4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="td.2.1">1.1</td>
<td id="td.2.2">2.2</td>
<td id="td.2.3">2.3</td>
<td id="td.1.3">2.4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="td.2.1">1.1</td>
<td id="td.2.2">3.2</td>
<td id="td.2.3">2.3</td>
<td id="td.2.3">3.4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="td.2.1">4.1</td>
<td id="td.2.2">4.2</td>
<td id="td.2.3">4.3</td>
<td id="td.2.3">4.4</td>
</tr>
</table>
<script>
//joinRows();
</script>
<br>
<button type="button" onclick="joinRows()">join cells</button>
```